# grub-mkconfig gives error in chroot environment

Tags: debian, grub2, chroot, grub2-mkconfig

I'm trying to make a Debian installation manually from scratch to an external disk within a live Debian CD.

I created a Debian Stretch rootfs via multistrap by following the instructions [from here (`44fbcc`)](https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-example/tree/44fbcc97d029687b7e42686f74db4e9f73195388).

Inside `chroot` environment, when it comes to Grub installation, I install the Grub2 to MBR:

```
debian:~# grub-install /dev/sdX --boot-directory=/boot
```

Command runs without error. When I need to create the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it throws the following error:

```
debian:~# grub-mkconfig
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
```

Yes, `/dev` is mounted along with `/sys`, `/proc` and `/run` [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-example/tree/44fbcc97d029687b7e42686f74db4e9f73195388/do-chroot.sh#L29).

How can I generate `grub.cfg` inside `chroot` environment?

Comment: Do you have `/sys` mounted in addition to /dev?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-example/blob/0130fd26f0f91110109099058ec71255a2c3e127/do-chroot.sh#L28).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaningful part of the error message was `cannot find a device for /`, because `mount` command does not output the device entry for `/`.

What I didn't tell in the question is that I was trying to directly install the rootfs into a BTRFS subvolume. Apparently, `chroot` can not detect the `/` device in this scenario.

Here is what I was currently doing: (`X` is the root partition (device), `Y` is the boot partition)

```
host:# mount /dev/X /mnt/mydiskroot
host:# btrfs sub create /mnt/mydiskroot/rootfs
host:# mkdir /mnt/mydiskroot/rootfs/boot
host:# mount /dev/Y /mnt/mydiskroot/rootfs/boot
host:# rsync -avP debian-stretch-rootfs/ /mnt/mydiskroot/rootfs
host:# do-chroot.sh /mnt/mydiskroot/rootfs
root@guest:/#  mount | awk '$3 == "/" {print}' # nothing shows up, so update-grub throws the mentioned error
```

Here is how I solved:

```
root@guest:/# exit
host:# mkdir /mnt/actual-rootfs
host:# mount -t btrfs -o subvol=rootfs,defaults /dev/X /mnt/actual-rootfs/
host:# umount /dev/Y
host:# mount /dev/Y /mnt/actual-rootfs/boot
host:# do-chroot.sh /mnt/actual-rootfs
root@guest:/# mount | awk '$3 == "/" {print}'
/dev/X on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/rootfs)
root@guest:/# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-11-amd64
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Really helped me out.. had been completely baffled about wth was going on with the bit about /dev not being mounted after I had already mounted it. Only difference for me was that since my btrfs partition was inside a luks2 container, after opening it with `cryptsetup`, I'd use a /dev/mapper path e.g. `mount -o "noatime,subvol=@fedora-root,compress=zstd:1" /dev/mapper/mappedname /mnt/mountpoint`. Other than that it worked perfectly and completely got me over that roadblock. Thank you, sir.