# How to encrypt an existing disk on Fedora without formatting?

Tags: fedora, encryption, btrfs, disk-encryption

There are a number of existing guides online that already cover how to reencrypt a disk, such as *maxschelpzig*'s response [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584275/533888) and the documentation in [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Encrypt_an_existing_unencrypted_file_system). However, the Arch wiki focuses more on systems that use `mkinitcpio` as opposed to `dracut`, and the existing StackExchange answer assumes an ext4 filesystem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This assumes a default Fedora installation, with the following Btrfs-based partitions:

- Root partition (Btrfs subvolumes "root" [mounted at `/`] and "home" [mounted at `/home`])
- Boot partition (mounted at `/boot`)
- EFI partition (*UEFI systems only*, mounted at `/boot/efi`)

**Requirements**

- A full-disk backup
- [cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup) (should be included, otherwise install with `dnf install cryptsetup`)
- At least 100 MiB of free space
- A rescue system that can unmount the root filesystem (ex. [Fedora live USB](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/))
- *NOTE:* The encryption screen will use the keyboard layout defined in `/etc/vconsole.conf` (set with `localectl`). The layout cannot be changed at boot time.

**Instructions**

1. Identify the root filesystem with `lsblk -f`. Store the UUID (format `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`) for later use.
2. Identify your current kernel version with `uname -r`, and save this value for later.
3. Reboot into the rescue system. Locate the root filesystem with `blkid --uuid <UUID>`, and run a check on the filesystem with `btrfs check <device>`
4. Mount the filesystem with `mount /dev/<device> /mnt`
5. Shrink the filesystem to make room for the LUKS header. At least 32 MiB is recommended, use `btrfs filesystem resize -32M /mnt`
6. Unmount the filesystem: `umount /mnt`
7. Encrypt the partition with `cryptsetup reencrypt --encrypt --reduce-device-size 32M /dev/<device>`, providing a passphrase when prompted.
8. Identify the encrypted LUKS partition with `lsblk -f` (note that the UUID has changed). Save this LUKS partition UUID for later use.
9. Open the partition, providing your passphrase when prompted: `cryptsetup open /dev/<device> system`
10. Mount the mapped filesystem with `mount /dev/mapper/system /mnt`
11. Resize the filesystem to use all the space: `btrfs filesystem resize max /mnt`, then unmount the filesystem with `umount /mnt`
12. Mount the ***root subvolume*** (the Linux filesystem root) with `mount -t btrfs -o "noatime,subvol=root,compress=zstd:1" /dev/mapper/system /mnt`
13. Identify the devices for the boot and EFI partitions with `lsblk`. Mount the boot filesystem (`mount /dev/<boot device> /mnt/boot`), followed by the EFI filesystem for UEFI systems (`mount /dev/<EFI device> /mnt/boot/efi`).
14. Bind-mount the pseudo filesystems `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc`, `/run`, and `/sys`, in the format of `mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
15. Open a shell within the filesystem: `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
16. Open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor, and modify the kernel parameters to identify the LUKS partition, and temporarily disable SELinux enforcing. Add these parameters, then save the changes and close the file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[other params] rd.luks.uuid=<LUKS partition UUID> enforcing=0"
```

17. Configure a relabelling of SELinux with `touch /.autorelabel`
18. Regenerate the GRUB config: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (also generate for `/etc/grub2.cfg`, and on UEFI systems `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg`)
19. Regenerate initramfs to ensure cryptsetup is enabled: `dracut --kver <kernel version> --force`
20. Exit the chroot
21. Unmount all filesystems in reverse order. (For filesystems mounted with `--bind`, the option `-l` can be used.) Close the LUKS partition with `cryptsetup close system`
22. Reboot and log into the regular system. You'll be asked for your passphrase to decrypt the system during boot.
23. Open `/etc/default/grub` in a text editor, and reenable SELinux enforcing by removing `enforcing=0` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Save and exit.
24. Relabel SELinux again with `touch /.autorelabel`.
25. **Repeat step 18** to regenerate the GRUB config.
26. Reboot and log into the system.

This answer heavily derives from *maxschelpzig*'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584275/533888) and [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Encrypt_an_existing_unencrypted_file_system). It also pulls from *ceremcem's* [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558623/533888). On March 16th 2023 a typo was corrected where `--reduce-device-size` incorrectly contained a space.